# Как вывести значение среди множества одинаковых классов beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Возможно сможет кто подсказать, как вытащить (print) только одну характеристику?
Например только ISBN (978-5-17-115171-3).

```
<div class="catalog-detail-properties">
                    <div class="h4">Характеристики</div>


                                                            <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                            <span class="name">Возрастное ограничение</span>
                            <span class="val">12+</span>
                        </div>
                                                            <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                            <span class="name">ISBN</span>
                            <span class="val" itemprop="isbn">978-5-17-115171-3</span>
                        </div>
                                                            <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                            <span class="name">Издательство</span>
                            <span class="val" itemprop="publisher"><a href="/publishers/izdatelstvo-ast/">АСТ</a></span>
                        </div>
                                                            <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                            <span class="name">Авторы</span>
                            <span class="val" itemprop="author"><a href="/authors/pushkin-aleksandr-sergeevich/">Пушкин Александр Сергеевич</a></span>
                        </div>
                                                            <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                            <span class="name">Серия</span>
                            <span class="val"><a href="/series/luchshaya-mirovaya-klassika/">Лучшая мировая классика</a></span>
                        </div>
                                                            <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                            <span class="name">Переплет</span>
                            <span class="val" itemprop="bookFormat">Твердый</span>
                        </div>
                                                            <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                            <span class="name">Вес</span>
                            <span class="val">0.299</span>
                        </div>
```

Метод с порядковым номером тега не подошел, так как порядок характеристик на странице с сайта может меняться от товара к товару.

Comment: Составить словарь `d`? Где ключами будут `text` из `"span.name"`, а значениями `text` из `"span.val"`. Тогда значение, например, `"ISBN"` можно будет получит как `d["ISBN"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте find_all чтоб найти все элементы, которые будут в виде списка, выберите нужный элемент, потом используйте метод text чтобы достать текст.

**main.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('some.txt', 'r') as html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    print(soup.find_all(class_='name')[1].text)  #ISBN
    print(soup.find_all(class_='val')[1].text)  #978-5-17-115171-3
```

**some.txt** -> html из вопроса

UDP, если неизвестно заранее, где находится нужная часть:

```
word = 'ISBN'

for count, tag in enumerate(soup.find_all(class_='name')):
   print(soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text if tag.text == 'ISBN' else 0) #978-5-17-115171-3
```

UDP2,

```
for count, tag in enumerate(soup.find_all(class_='name')):
    if tag.text == 'ISBN':
       vol = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
```

Comment: *>>Метод с порядковым номером тега не подошел, так как порядок характеристик на странице с сайта может меняться от товара к товару*.

Comment: значит, можете через for перебрать

Comment: @JackWolf Срасботало, спасибо. Возник еще вопрос, как удалить теперь пустые значения (такие как '0')? .replace не действует.

Comment: добавил в ответе

Comment: @JackWolf Все работает! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Отлично, пометьте, пожалуйста, ответ как верный (галочка)